# how to disable form resizing using c#

Tags: winforms, resize, c#-3.0

How to disable form resizing using c# ?

I just want to avoid resizing my form by user.

I tried changing `FormBorderStyle` But it doesn't work
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code used and telll us what is the initial value for FormBorderStyle? FormBorderStyle works as expected so it is unclear why is not working for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the FormBorderStyle property

```
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

You may also want to remove the minimize and maximize buttons:

```
form1.MaximizeBox = false;
form1.MinimizeBox = false;
```